# Installing Konica minolta PP1400w

Tags: installation, printing

New Installation Ubuntu 13.10 Samba4 installed
Printer HP Color LaserJet and Canon 4550 already successfully installed and networked to
windows 7 machine.
Printer connected to machine via USB and detected by add printer software however when I continue it either stalls or give a installing driver screen and then returns to the select device screen.
The printer was installed in previous versions of Ubuntu up to 13.04

Answer (score 0):

That printer has never been supported on Linux by Konica. You might try installing the driver from Terminal to see if that gets you a better outcome.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-min12xxw
```